# Route from one component to another reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have my app like that

```
 <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <header>Project Issues</header>
        </Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Issues />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Inside **Issues** component, I choose to render one of two components based on a window width condition, one of the two components is called **TwoPagesLayout**, in this component when the user clicks on some text, it should go to another component called **IssueDetails**.
Here's the part of the **TwoPagesLayout component**:

```
 {issues.map((issue: any) => (
        <div>
          <Link to="/Details" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <p className="issue-title">{issue.title}</p>
          </Link>
          <hr></hr>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/Details">
              <IssueDetails issue={issue} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      ))}
```

The problem is when I click on the text, it goes to that url "http://localhost:3000/Details" but it appears as a blank white page, it doesn't render what is inside the page.

Hope I have made it clear, I am new to react so I think the question maybe sounds common.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <Issues />
</Route>
```

Since you've marked this as `exact`, once the url changes to /Details, it no longer matches, and so `Issues` unmounts. Since `Issues` unmounts, so too does its descendant `IssueDetails`. You probably want to do:

```
<Route path="/">
  <Issues />
</Route>
```

Comment: Ohh okay I see it loaded IssueDetails component but not as expected. it loaded both the components IssueDetails  and TwoPagesLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The Issues component will only render on the "/" path. When the page is showing "/Details" the Issues component will not render, and that includes the nested Router.

For this reason (they’re confusing), I personally try to avoid nested routers, so I would suggest keeping all the Route components together unless you have a reason otherwise!

Comment: Thank you! the reason behind I didn't keep all the route components together because I need to send this state issue={issue}( which is declared inside the loop) when rendering the Details component.